# Digital Signature Verification Error (Signature is invalid)

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I had integrate digital signature in existing pdf file using .pfx file and  used PDFBOX (java) for this task. For that i had refereed the CreateVisibleSignature2.java example and pdf was successfully generated. but when we open pdf file then it shows Error like '**Invalid Signature**'.
pfx file is working fine while i sign document manually in Acrobat Reader, but the file which generated using program are unable to verify signature.
i have use PDFBOX-3.0.0.-RC1 jar. [Error while opening pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCbrD.png)

is there any other open source/free utility available for digital signature in java ?

Comment: Have you used the example CreateVisibleSignature2.java as is or did you apply any changes? That example usually works... nonetheless, you should try the latest 2.x version, 3.0.0-RC1 is merely a release *candidate*, so there may be issues. (And yes, there also are other open source signing options, but if PDFBox fails in your environment, those other options may fail as well, so you had better get the PDFBox example working for you before testing the other options. )

Comment: I tried with pdfbox-2.0.3 version but issue not resolved. In CreateVisibleSignature2.java program i had add the code for pfx file and commented tsaUrl code.

Comment: The *latest 2.x* is not 2.0.3 but 2.0.26. And in that version `CreateVisibleSignature2` is known to work. If it doesn't for you, you do something wrong. Without further details, we cannot help further.

Comment: Also make sure to use the latest bouncycastle version, 1.70.